# Using Wikipedia API continue parameter

Tags: http, get, wikipedia-api

I am using the wikipedia API to query for a search word, for example by making a `GET` request to this `URL`:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&utf8=1&srprop=snippet&continue=&srsearch=Slovenia
```

This query returns a total of 51429 hits, but will only display the first 10 results. From reading the [documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Continuing_queries) on this topic, I gather that to get the next 10 results I should pass in the continue parameter.

The relevant parameters in the API response are here:

```
continue: {
   sroffset: 10,
   continue: "-||"
}
```

So I build my url in the following way:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&utf8=1&srprop=snippet&continue=-||&srsearch=Slovenia
```

But the URL returns the same set of results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You should pass on the contents of the `continue` field. I.e. `sroffset=
10&contiue=-||`.

Comment: Isn't this what I have been doing? If you check the 2nd URL it has the continue=-|| parameter

Comment: Not `sroffset=10` though.